# I have search a lot on xamarin forms file encryption but could not find anything on internet

Tags: xamarin.forms

How to encrypt and decry-pt a file in xamarin forms ? The file can be of any type it may be image file , text file etc

Answer (score 0):

There aren't a lot of easy-to-use choices, but PCL Crypto is a popular one, and seems to be reasonably well maintained.  https://www.nuget.org/packages/pclcrypto

Comment: Yeah I know about PCLCrypto my question is that how to encrypt a file in xamarin,PCLCrypto is just used to encrypt a string ...

Comment: You can encrypt strings with it, but PCLCrypto can operate on byte[] -- see the declaration of ICryptographicEngine.Encrypt/Decrypt here https://github.com/AArnott/PCLCrypto/blob/master/src/PCLCrypto.Shared.Common/ICryptographicEngine.cs . If you need files encrypted, you need to write the code to read the original file as a byte array, run it through PCLCrypto, and then write the result back out.